# Create a python function that accepts dataframe and column(s)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, spyder

I'm trying to create a function that accepts dataframe columns.

Something along the lines of the below pseudo code..

```
def tb_mend_format(df, col):
   
    if df[col][:3] == 'TBK':
        return 'TB ' + df[col][7:]
    else:
        return df[col]
```

Is it possible to then pass a dataframe and column(s) in the below fashion as required?
The plan is to create a reusable function.

```
tb_mend_format(df1, df['Key'])
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just to confirm, `col` is a column name (eg a string), yes?  The example function call looks inconsistent with the function body.

Comment: Col is a pandas column/series

Answer (score 0):

Probably you meant something like this?

```
def tb_mend_format(df, col: Union[pd.Series, str]):

    if isinstance(col, pd.Series):
         series = col
    else:
         series = df[col]

    if series[:3] == 'TBK':
        return 'TB ' + series[7:]
    else:
        return series

# both works
tb_mend_format(df, 'Key')
tb_mend_format(df, df['Key'])
```

This code, however, won't work if `col` is a list/tuple of str (column names).

In Pandas, a column is represented by a `pd.Series` object and I guess you meant `column` by the "name" of a column or Series, in `str` type (or list/tuple of `str` for multiple columns).

Comment: Yes col is pd.series. However, this doesn't seem to work.